# Can't style font-color nor font-weight on my print view with @media print

Tags: css, printing

I am building a single-page application (with Angular) that basically consists on a multi-step form which can be printed when finished.

Here you can see the look of a sample section of the print-view, with colors and different font-weights:

[image: Completed form]

What happens is, when I click print (whether through the browser menu or through a button I provide with `javascript:if(window.print)window.print()`) the print document's font is all black and has only one weight.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Print document]

I tried re-styling it using `@media print` to no avail. I can change the font-size and the margins/padding for instance, but I am not able to change the color or font-weight of my text.

For instance:

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        color: yellow;
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}
```

The above snippet does reduce my font-size but not the color.

Those thin, grey-ish borders you can see separating each item do appear in their original color however.

Why is this? How can I have this print document with the same font color and weight that I see on the browser?

**EDIT:** There are no printer settings other than the very basic options we have in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Afraid there isn't enough information here. Your color may be getting over ruled by something else in the cascade. Put an `!important` on it just for testing purposes. If that works, you have a cascade problem.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, I'm a bit clueless as to what's going on here. I did try your suggestion: color: yellow !important; still yields black text.

Comment: maybe you should check your print settings in the print dialog? check that your print option is not set to black and white...

Comment: Ok, since `!important` did't fix it, it doesn't sound like a css problem. Start looking into things like Jag suggested.

Comment: I don't think I have any such printer settings.

Comment: Can this be related to the font-face I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` directly on the element in CSS. i.e.:

```
.my-element{ 
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Comment: In Chrome this makes no difference for me (Version 86.0.4240.111)